# Gradle not able to download android packages

Tags: android, docker, gradle, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

I have a docker container with Android SDK on it. I am trying to build a Android Java application using gradlew. The thing is if i need to download from the internet I need to use proxy. For which I have configured my android and gradle to use the proxy setting.

I am able to download packages from the command line using command

> android update sdk

But when i run gradlew it is able to download the dependency from jcentre but it fails trying to download some Android package i think. I have pasted the error message below.

cat /root/.android/androidtool.cfg

```
sdkman.force.http=true
http.proxyHost=gateway.bns 
http.proxyPort=8000
```

cat gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=xyz.abc
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8000
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.abc
systemProp.https.proxyHost=xyz.abc
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.abc
```

./gradlew clean test assemble

```
DK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /sdk/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Error:

    File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    Failed to download any source lists!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever are using a plugin version which is more recent than 2.2.3, I think this could be linked to :  [Unable to update sdk dependencies with latest android gradle plugin](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37135524)